# Why does Rey wear the same outfit in different environments?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, clothing, rey

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey can be seen wearing the same outfit wherever she goes.
She wears it on a desert planet:
[image]

On an ice planet:
[image]

On a jungle planet:

[image]

Why is this? Shouldn't different environments require different clothes?

### Why does Rey wear the same outfit in different environments?

Comment: Because she's an impoverished scavenger with almost nothing to her name, and she left her home planet - and her wardrobe - behind, suddenly and unexpectedly.  She spent a couple of days with Finn and Han and Chewie, then she was imprisoned, then she broke out of prison.  Finally, she left to find Luke.  At no point did she have the opportunity to get her clothes from Jakku.

Comment: Also, she is a force sensitive, so she could barely feel the cold or other harsh weather conditions...

Comment: Rey wears new clothes at the end of TFA: https://www.google.com/search?q=rey+ending+force+awakens&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS604US604&hl=en-US&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2gOy2o6vKAhUG7GMKHSZNDwUQ_AUICCgB#imgrc=qFxnk6ZAOW5R4M%3A

Comment: Tatooine fashion has always been a hit.

Comment: That last pic is Takodana. Not Ach-to.

Comment: Finn is wearing the same thing in two of these shots also.

Comment: Han didn't trust her enough yet to let her borrow his clothes like Lando in Return of the Jedi, I guess.

Comment: When you find something that fits, why mess with it?

Comment: @WadCheber So **that’s** why she was so eager to go back to Jakku all the time!

Comment: She didn't exactly have time to pack her suitcase...

Comment: The first true case of "I have nothing to wear"

Comment: This is a horrible oversight by the costume department, since they're only going to be able to sell one Rey action figure now.

Comment: I'm sure Ray was freezing; but adrenalin, fear, anxiety, determination, and a strong connection with the Force will probably keep you functioning well in unfamiliar climates. Most deserts, granted Ray's planet is fictional, get frigid at night.

Comment: I'm sorry.  The nitpicking with this movie has gone thermonuclear.

Comment: She didn't have any other outfits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The canon answer (offered by the [Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)) is that Rey was simply too busy saving the whole.damn.galaxy to think about changing her outfit. When she arrives at the Starkiller Base she briefly borrows Finn's jacket (seen in the deleted scene pictured below) but just shrugs off the discomfort in order to get on with her mission.

[image]

Then, when she gets a few minutes to spare, she changes her outfit (and hopefully has a shower) before meeting Luke.

[image]

Comment: Even with the new outfit she clearly couldn't afford one with sleeves and still has to wrap cloth bandages around her arms...

Comment: @BMWurm - After a lifetime of wearing something similar, she probably wouldn't feel dressed without them.

Comment: The exposed upperarm/shoulder is actually seen in a number of outfits, most notably Padme's. Given Padme's wealth and social standing, seems likely this is a fashionable look in the galaxy. Even ~50 years on, I wouldn't be surprised to see it, especially with the revitalization of the republic encouraging "retro" styles.

Comment: Perhaps the stench is why neither of them could bring themselves to harness the power of speech.

Comment: The wraps are to stabilize the joints for fighting. You don't need them on your shoulders. That would just inhibit your movement.

Comment: "Saving the whole.damn.galaxy" is not part of what Rey does during TFA. I'm sure it will be her duty in future movies, but in TFA she captured, fights to escape, and then has the confrontation with Kylo that is inconsequential to the destruction Starkiller Base.

Comment: @Mason240: apparently, you missed the fact that she played a vital role in said destruction of said Starkiller Base.

Comment: @Mason240 - Erm, she lets the strike squad (Finn, Chewie, Han) into the base. Without her, Han would be stuck outside [fiddling with wires](https://media0.giphy.com/media/x0w62ZcupOMak/200.gif) again.

Comment: @Richard: Does she? I don't remember that. From what I remember, Han/Chewie/Finn are going to the base to save her / deactivate the shields anyway, and get in before they find her. She, at that point, is hiding near a shuttle bay.

Comment: @Jeeva True, if you're talking about *Starkiller Base* itself, but not the energy distribution thingy the attack is supposed to blow up, the fighters cannot make a dent so the ground forces decide to use their still unused explosives to blow it from within. To let them in, Rey rips something out of some relay(?) which opens up a corridor full of blast doors for Han & Chewie to enter. Finn and Rey herself take a ladder to that balcony where they later on watch the confrontation on the walkway below...

Comment: @Richard Actually her escape puts that sector on alert making the strike force's task harder.

Comment: @PStag - It sounds like this has the makings of a site question - "What was Rey's contribution to the destruction of the Starkiller?"

Comment: Just copied this from the closed question

Comment: I hope it was an unusually warm day that she met Luke, because you wouldn't want much of your body exposed if you're standing on top of one of the Skelligs in September.  It's gorgeous out there, but it's wild.

Answer (score 89):

I'm not aware of an explicit answer in the movie or the novelization, but it seems pretty self explanatory to me:

1. Rey is an orphaned, impoverished scavenger who lives a hand to mouth existence.  She probably doesn't have many clothes to begin with.
2. She leaves her home on Jakku suddenly and unexpectedly, and doesn't have a chance to pack a change of clothes.  In fact, as far as I can recall, she leaves with nothing but the clothes on her back and her staff.
3. She hangs out with Finn, gets swept up with Han and Chewbacca, and goes to Takodana with them.
4. She is captured by Kylo Ren and held prisoner for a while.
5. She breaks out of her holding cell, fights Kylo, and escapes to the Resistance base.
6. She is asked to go find Luke, and sets out to do so pretty quickly.  Here, she is finally wearing a different outfit.  This is to be expected, because she has finally had some free time to get new clothes and put them on.

So she might have owned only one outfit in the first place, she didn't have a chance to buy or find more clothes until after she returned from the Starkiller base, and she had had other things on her mind the whole time until then.

*On a side note, Han wears his white shirt, black vest, and striped blue pants throughout much of Episode IV, and Chewbacca hasn't changed his clothes (i.e., his bandolier and messenger bag) since the Clone Wars, so Rey's failure to change her outfit isn't particularly unusual...  And Vader and the Emperor have been wearing the same thing since the end of episode III.  Come to think of it, the Jedi wore the same robes every day for as long as they lived.  I guess the galaxy far, far away has some very advanced deodorant.*

Comment: Rey is wearing a new set of clothes when she heads off to the ocean planet to find Luke. This backs up the rest of your answer, since clearly she did change her outfit as soon as circumstances allowed. She also borrows the Finn/Poe jacket for a short time while on Starkiller Base. (In the scene where Rey and Finn climb the ladder up the side of the thermal regulator building.)

Comment: Yoda: *Let's put it on.*
Obi-Wan: *Put what on?*
Yoda: *The last robe you'll ever wear.*

Comment: Han did get a new jacket, at least. Allegedly.

Comment: *Yoda: "Put it on let us."

Comment: To be fair, of course, we don't really know anything about how laundry worked in the Star Wars universe (at least not to my knowledge). It could have been all Jetson-like—just put your clothes in the washer, and 15 seconds later, you have a spotless and perfectly repaired set of clothes. Or perhaps the Sith and the Jedi just had lots and lots of completely identical outfits to choose from.

Comment: For those who don't get the reference or are having trouble placing it, @Ghanima is referencing [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmrwj6DDt-4) from Men In Black (1997).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or it could even be that [their clothing just doesn't need washing](http://mashable.com/2013/04/30/no-wash-shirt-woolprince/#AGfT6.CiJEqo), but hopefully they still bathe..

Comment: "very advanced deodorant"

Comment: "she leaves with nothing but the clothes on her back and her staff. "...  and something else which, earlier in the movie, she said was not for sale.

Comment: @TOOGAM  - I consider BB-8 a person, not a possesion.

Comment: one thing I jus got.......the wookie is cold on that planet........but she is in desert robes

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I believe I've read something about Jedi being sworn to poverty and only owning a set of clothes and a lightsaber.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Han has a different outfit in each of the three original films. He has a black vest in ANH, a blue jacket in Empire, and a different black vest (with pockets) in ROTJ (he also wears a brown military coat for part of ROTJ). In ANH he's wearing blue pants with a red stripe, while in the latter two he has brown pants with a gold stripe.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks, I was wondering where that was from. I knew it sounded familiar

Answer (score 6):

I'm coming late to the party here, but there's one fact everyone else seems to have overlooked:

### deserts can be freezing cold at night.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_climate) (emphasis mine):

> Some desert locations consistently experience very high temperatures all year long, even during wintertime. These locations feature some of the highest annual average temperatures recorded on Earth, averages which can exceed 30 °C (86 °F). This last feature is seen in some parts of deserts of Africa and Arabia. During colder periods of the year, **night-time temperatures can drop to freezing or below** due to the exceptional radiation loss under the clear skies.

So the clothing Rey is used to wearing on a desert planet should be such that she can cope with wearing it **both in conditions of extreme heat and in those of extreme cold**. It makes sense that such a versatile garment would also do her just fine on an ice planet and even perhaps a jungle planet (although humidity is the one thing desert garb might *not* be able to take).

Also, as pointed out by other users, she's tough and isn't going to let a little thing like uncomfortable temperatures get in her way. This is a particularly good argument because **she's already used to cold temperatures** from the desert nights. Plus she doesn't seem the type of woman to be worrying about her dress all the time - she just uses whatever clothes she has and gets on with it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what TVTropes has to offer:

> [Limited Wardrobe](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LimitedWardrobe): The character always wears the same outfit, regardless of the setting or season.

[...]

> This trope is especially prevalent in shows with heavy merchandising tie-ins, where it is considered important to maximize the resemblance between the characters and their action figure counterparts.

And I guess the Star Wars saga [fits the category well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNZove4OTtI).

Comment: That theory doesn't work for Padme...