# Wasn't Rey cold on Starkiller base? Shouldn't this have impacted her somehow?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Rey grew up in an environment that was desert like. For her entire life prior to the movie, she was used to a warm environment (at least daytime).

[image]

It's clearly snowing, but she is wearing the same outfit she routinely wore on a planet that was described by Star Wars wiki with a climate of "[hot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jakku)." We don't know how cold the base was, but it's snowing, so clearly colder.

While I might not be a Jedi-in-training, when I go to an environment that is significantly colder it affects me physically. And I live in a climate which has seasons - not having grown in a desert for 20 years.

Shouldn't Rey have been somehow physically affected by this? Or at least.. been really cold?

<sub>Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115000/11841)</sub>