# Where did Rey get her new clothes?

Tags: star-wars, rey

At the end of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, when the resistance was finally able to find Luke's location, we can see Rey with a new outfit and she goes to Ach-To to find Luke with wearing it. But how did she manage to get her new clothes?

[image: Rey is wearing a new outfit]
<sub>*Rey in her new outfit.*</sub>

[image: Here, when the resistance retrieves the map, Rey was still wearing her old clothes]
<sub>*Rey in her old outfit.*</sub>

Comment: Related, not a dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115000/19561

Comment: Wal-Mart probably. IDK. Funny thing about people is that they have a tendency to wear different things as time goes on. Exceptions in SQB's link obviously.

Comment: Yeah, the Rebellion would never reward her with a piece of cloth and some sewing appliances. A medal, sure, but never clothes or anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a *"flight jacket"*. Given that the whole base is a staging area for the Rebellion fleet she almost certainly requisitioned it new from the Rebel  quartermaster or just picked it up wherever they stash clothing that used to belong to one of the pilots who got themselves dead.

> Rey headed to the launch area with R2-D2. Leia waited near the
> boarding ramp. **She adjusted the fit of the new flight jacket Rey wore**.
> “I’m proud of what you’re about to do.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>